# Getting a legacy-install-failure for package greenlet while trying to install requirements

Tags: python3, 22.04

I am using Ubuntu version 22.04 LTS and python version 3.10.4. I am trying to install requirements.txt for the project that I am doing but I am running into the issue mentioned in the title. The requirements.txt file specifies greenlet to be of this version: greenlet==0.4.13. However, this is the error I get:

```
    Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
      Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py) ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/greenlet.o
      greenlet.c: In function ‘g_calltrace’:
      greenlet.c:523:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘use_tracing’; did you mean ‘tracing’?
        523 |         tstate->use_tracing = 0;
            |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
            |                 tracing
      greenlet.c:526:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘use_tracing’; did you mean ‘tracing’?
        526 |         tstate->use_tracing = (tstate->tracing <= 0 &&
            |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
            |                 tracing
      greenlet.c: In function ‘g_initialstub’:
      greenlet.c:810:25: warning: ‘PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        810 |                         result = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
            |                         ^~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:130,
                   from greenlet.h:8,
                   from greenlet.c:5:
      /usr/include/python3.10/ceval.h:17:43: note: declared here
         17 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      greenlet.c: In function ‘green_dealloc’:
      greenlet.c:984:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        984 |                 Py_REFCNT(self) = 1;
            |                                 ^
      greenlet.c:1013:21: error: lvalue required as decrement operand
       1013 |                 if (--Py_REFCNT(self) != 0) {
            |                     ^~
      greenlet.c:1017:41: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
       1017 |                         Py_REFCNT(self) = refcnt;
            |                                         ^
      greenlet.c:1021:25: error: ‘_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘_Py_DECREF’?
       1021 |                         _Py_DEC_REFTOTAL;
            |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |                         _Py_DECREF
      greenlet.c:1021:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
      Running setup.py clean for greenlet
    Failed to build greenlet
    Installing collected packages: greenlet, geographiclib, chardet, Werkzeug, SQLAlchemy, requests, redis, python-json-logger, python-http-client, python-dateutil, protobuf, meinheld, gunicorn, geopy, sendgrid, mysql-connector-python, httpie

      Running setup.py install for greenlet ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      × Running setup.py install for greenlet did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [44 lines of output]
          running install
          /home/shreeman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
            warnings.warn(
          running build
          running build_ext
          building 'greenlet' extension
          creating build
          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
          x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/greenlet.o
          greenlet.c: In function ‘g_calltrace’:
          greenlet.c:523:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘use_tracing’; did you mean ‘tracing’?
            523 |         tstate->use_tracing = 0;
                |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
                |                 tracing
          greenlet.c:526:17: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘use_tracing’; did you mean ‘tracing’?
            526 |         tstate->use_tracing = (tstate->tracing <= 0 &&
                |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
                |                 tracing
          greenlet.c: In function ‘g_initialstub’:
          greenlet.c:810:25: warning: ‘PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            810 |                         result = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
                |                         ^~~~~~
          In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:130,
                   from greenlet.h:8,
                   from greenlet.c:5:
          /usr/include/python3.10/ceval.h:17:43: note: declared here
          17 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
             |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          greenlet.c: In function ‘green_dealloc’:
          greenlet.c:984:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
            984 |                 Py_REFCNT(self) = 1;
                |                                 ^
          greenlet.c:1013:21: error: lvalue required as decrement operand
           1013 |                 if (--Py_REFCNT(self) != 0) {
                |                     ^~
          greenlet.c:1017:41: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
           1017 |                         Py_REFCNT(self) = refcnt;
                |                                         ^
          greenlet.c:1021:25: error: ‘_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘_Py_DECREF’?
           1021 |                         _Py_DEC_REFTOTAL;
                |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                |                         _Py_DECREF
          greenlet.c:1021:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
          error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
          [end of output]

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: legacy-install-failure

    × Encountered error while trying to install package.
    ╰─> greenlet

    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have googled this error but every solution that I have tried ends up not working. Either the error is related to an earlier version of ubuntu or python but not the specific combination that I have described here. Any help would be welcome!

Thanks!
Umesh

Comment: You say you're using 22.04 but your tags say 20.04.  Python in 22.04 is version 3.10, not 3.8, so I'm confused where you're getting Python 3.8 from.  The issue you're having though is a compiler failure problem, and suggests that perhaps greenlet is missing dependencies, or is not up to spec with the C version that is installed in 22.04.

Comment: Yeah, just changed it. Thank you. My version is 22.04. And, yeah, my python is 3.10. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ThomasWard, what do you suggest then? How do I implement the things that you have put out? I am not really familiar with compiler failures. Further, I have used windows all my life and recently have started using linux.

Answer (score 2):

I have python3.10 and i'm trying to install from requirements.txt which contain "greenlet==0.4.17 ; python_version > '3.7'". My solution is change "greenlet==0.4.17" to "greenlet==1.1.0" and it worked.

Comment: how you change greenlet==0.4.17 to greenlet==1.1.0 ubuntu what's the cmd?

Comment: by text editor, do it manually