# The version of python and the version of ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

I try to install Elastalert in ubuntu 22.04 and when I put this cmd: pip3 install Elastalert I find this Error: [Getting a legacy-install-failure for package greenlet while trying to install requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413416/getting-a-legacy-install-failure-for-package-greenlet-while-trying-to-install-re)
try to enter in this link and anser my question
How to  change "greenlet==0.4.17" to "greenlet==1.1.0"?

Comment: i edit my question see now Nmath thanks for your response

Comment: The only way to change the greenlet version to use is to repackage teh Elastalert package yourself and define the higher dependency of greenlet.  This should be done by the Elastalert maintainer though, so if they are on `pip3` or such you should find out the developer and contact the developer to fix dependencies.

Comment: that's mean ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.10 AND ELASTICSEARCH 8.4.1 can't run ElastALERT  i try many times to run this tool but i can't how?